# How I can use keras layer neural network in data without label?(just with some inputs and no lables)

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras-layer

I want use keras for deep forward neural network but without using model fit. somthing like this but using keras not tf.layer:

```
 h_1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=inputs,   units=self.n_1, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, kernel_regularizer=regularizer)
 h_2 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=h_1, units=self.n_2, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, kernel_regularizer=regularizer)
 h_3 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=h_2, units=self.n_3, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, kernel_regularizer=regularizer)
 h_4 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=h_3, units=self.n_3, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, kernel_regularizer=regularizer)
 out = tf.layers.dense(inputs=h_4, units=self.a_dim, activation=tf.nn.tanh, kernel_regularizer=regularizer)
```

this is class that I have built for keras neurL network:

```
from keras import backend as K

from keras.layers import Layer

from keras import activations

import tensorflow as tf

class actorLayer(Layer):



def __init__(self, output_dim,activation=None, **kwargs):

    self.output_dim = output_dim        
    self.activation = activations.get(activation)        
    #self.batch_size = batch_size        
    super(actorLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

def build(self, input_shape):
    # Create a trainable weight variable for this layer.
    self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel', 
                                  shape=(input_shape[1], self.output_dim),
                                  initializer='uniform',
                                  trainable=True)
    super(actorLayer, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this at the end

def call(self, x):
    #print("----------")
    #print(tf.shape(x))
    #print(tf.shape(self.kernel))
    #print("----------")
    return self.activation(K.dot(x, self.kernel))

def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
    return (input_shape, self.output_dim)
```

and this is how I use it:

```
            x_in = Input(shape=(7,))

            x = actorLayer(128,activation='relu')(x_in)
            x = actorLayer(64,activation='relu')(x)
            x = actorLayer(64,activation='relu')(x)
            x = actorLayer(16)(x)
            x = actorLayer(2)(x)
```

I need sth like tf.layer that I can use its output(out in above code) 
I use `model = Model(inputs = x_in,outputs = x)` to build my model but I don not know how to use its output and return out and I can not use model fit.

I have used `out = model(input)` but it does not work. I use this NN for reinforcement learning and I need to return its output and then optimize its weights

Comment: model.predict(x) ?

Comment: when I use model.predict I get this error: ```ValueError: When feeding symbolic tensors to a model, we expect thetensors to have a static batch size. Got tensor with shape: (None, 7)``` It`s need a real data but I want to feet tf.placeholder and train the network in other module @viceriel

Comment: I find this :[ https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer]  and i write this code :

Comment: `x_in = Input(shape=(7,))                                                                                     x = actorLayer(128,activation='relu')(x_in)                                                          x = actorLayer(64,activation='relu')(x)
x = actorLayer(64,activation='relu')(x)
x = actorLayer(16)(x)                                                                                         
_x = actorLayer(2)(x)`

Comment: `#layer_name = 'my_layer'  intermediate_layer_model = Model(inputs=model.input,
                                 outputs=model.get_layer(_x).output)
                intermediate_output = intermediate_layer_model.predict(__inputs)
                out = intermediate_output ``` but I get this error : ```TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is defined, and use TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs conditioned on the value of a tensor.`@viceriel